# Run a loop without merging the cells

Tags: cells, infinite-loop

I have to run a loop of a certain variable than spans through the entire notebook. However the notebook has already been divided into different sections; merging these sections will be a pain and break the structure of the notebook. What can I do? I looked at some answer:
[Do-Command around entire Notebook (by iterating it from another notebook?)](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/121371/do-command-around-entire-notebook-by-iterating-it-from-another-notebook)
but firstly I could not understand it, and secondly, for each loop I need to save hundreds of variable.
The tags don't fit my question but unfortunately I do not have reputation to change, sorry about that.
Thank you all!

Comment: I think this would be a great moment to learn about [modular programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_programming). By modularizing, you can call the different parts of your code from a centralized small loop.

Comment: [This may help](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/135557/5467). It is intended for people who write programs for themselves (some kind of "end user programmers") as opposed to progammers who develop program for/with others, basically for those who write some pieces of code in different cells and want to execute the whole code at the end.